# Attempting to create a bar graph in C using information from file

Tags: c, graph, codeblocks

i'm trying to create a program using basic c constructs and loops that reads math quiz scores from a file and prints the scores as stars (like a bargraph). The program will attempt read the file and visually portray how the student is performing in different 
areas of mathematics (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and 
division).

The input file looks something like this:

```
2 
Bobby 
6 10 
70 80
50 60 
4 5 
Joel
7 12
20 25
4 5
3 10
```

The first line represents the number of total students in the file. After this each of the students will have 5 lines of individual data. The first of these lines is the student name, and the next 4 are scores for the individual areas of math 
(5 out of 6, 70 out of 80, etc.)

And im attempting to receive an output similar to this example:

```
Bobby
+: ******** 
-: ****** 
*: ***** 
/: **** 
Joel
+: **** 
-: ******** 
*: *** 
/: *******
```

I know I need to use loops and ifp(internal file pointers) to achieve this, but im not quite sure how to implement them to read the individual lines of the program, as this is my first time using an input file in C.

** Fourth Edit- Objective completed!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

//int main
int main() {

    FILE * ifp;
    ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    FILE * ofp;
    ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    int students = 0, i, j;
    int sum = 0;
    int perc;
    int score1,score2;
    char name [10];

    //read the first line for # of students
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &students);

    //Loop for both students
    for (i=0; i<students; i++) {

                fscanf(ifp, "%s", &name);
                fprintf(ofp, "%s:", name);

                fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &score1, &score2);
                perc = (10 * score1/score2);
                fprintf(ofp, "\n +:");
                for(j=0; j<perc; j++){
                    fprintf(ofp, "*");
                }
                fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &score1, &score2);
                perc = (10 * score1/score2);
                fprintf(ofp, "\n -:");
                for(j=0; j<perc; j++){
                    fprintf(ofp, "*");
                }

                fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &score1, &score2);
                perc = (10 * score1/score2);
                fprintf(ofp, "\n *:");
                for(j=0; j<perc; j++){
                    fprintf(ofp, "*");
                }
                fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &score1, &score2);
                perc = (10 * score1/score2);
                fprintf(ofp, "\n /:");
                for(j=0; j<perc; j++){
                    fprintf(ofp, "*");
                }
                    fprintf(ofp, "\n");
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);

return 0;
}
```

It seems my previous graph error was a simple order of operations error on my part. Thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Well, What I would do, after finding the average of the score with math, I would make a for loop, and change the loop variable(i or j or whatever) to the average, and print stars in the for loop.

```
//Here is an example of a for loop that loops 20 times
    for ( n=0; n < 20; n++ )
{
   // whatever here...
}
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you can count on your input file always being formatted the way you describe, then you don't need to worry much about format checking (although it is always a good idea).  Still check for errors where appropriate (file operations, fgets, etc.)  I don't think you need to use a switch case statement.  A for loop should suffice because you can go through the steps needed to handle one student record, then let the for loop repeat those steps for any remaining students.  I would do the following:

```
/* declare variables */
int num_students    // the number of students on the first line
char name[50], line[100]    // student name, a line from the input file
int addition_score, addition_max    // student's addition score, max addition score possible
int subtraction_score, subtraction max
/* ints for multiply and divide scores as well */
float percent   // used for _score / _max (re-use for + - * and /)
FILE input_file, output_file

// open input file for reading
// open output file for writing
// fgets line from input file
// sscanf to extract num_students
// for(c=0; c<num_students; ++c) {

    //fgets name

    //fgets the line containing the addition scores
    //sscanf line for addition_score and addition_max
    //same two commands for -, *, and /

    //percent = (float)addition_score / addition_max 
    //output the student's name to output file
    //figure out how to represent the float in stars (I'll leave this up to you)
    //output a line containing "+:" and your stars to the output file

    //repeat that procedure for -, *, and /
   } // end for loop
// close input file
// close output file
return 0;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your step by step instructions and advice. They really helped me wrap my head around the objective!